# error using Python Elasticserarch-py package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

So I am trying to create a connection to AWS ES.  I have successfully connected to my S3 bucket in the same zone.  However, when I try to connect to ES, I get this message every time.

```
Please install requests to use RequestsHttpConnection.
```

I have imported the correct module but nothing seems to fix this issue.  Here is my code

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from boto3 import client, logging, s3, Session

host = 'search-esdomain-t3rfr4trerdgfdh6t4t43ef.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts = host,
    connection_class = RequestsHttpConnection,
    http_auth = ('user', 'password'),
    use_ssl = True,
    verify_certs = False)
```

This looks the same as every example I can find but for some reason it will not connect.

This is with Python 3.5 and my dev environment is VS 2015.

Comment: what is the output of  `python3 -c 'import requests'` ?

Comment: importerror: no module named 'requests'

Comment: you need to install the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

Comment: well crap.  I guess I figured the ElasticSearch package contained its own request module.  Guess not.  Thank you.  Add that as an answer and I will give you credit.

Comment: glad it helped have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation for [elasticsearch-py](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/transports.html).

> Note that the RequestsHttpConnection requires requests to be installed.

There is a need to explictly install the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module if it does not already exist in the `PYTHONPATH`